"Filter failed" error in Redhat 7.9
Good afternoon, I would like to know if you can help me with this error in Red Hat 7.9, when trying to print via CUPS on a printer created by SMB I get the following error:
retenido desde Tue May 14 12:36:32 2024 "Filter failed"
When I validate the CUPS error_log I get these two messages:
Unable to encrypt connection from 10.0.128
error:14094416: SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown

alert certificate unknown that's the problem. The certificate is issued from an untrusted authority.
